# jQuery remove class after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my own drop down navigation working, so when a user clicks on one of the links a page overlay will appear. I just need when they click again the page overlay removes.

Here is my code to add the overlay

```
$('#nav li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#page-overlay').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

And a working DEMO is here - http://dsm.fishtankcreative.co.uk/

I just need help for when a user clicks off the navigation the page overlay class disappear.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('#nav li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#page-overlay').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Note: I don't think there is a need to use `.siblings().removeClass('active')`, as you are not adding the active class to any other elements

Comment: Thats great thanks, but one question if you don't mind. [link](http://dsm.fishtankcreative.co.uk/) if you click on Kingfisher in the navigation it works but if you go from kingfisher to DSM then click off it doesn't work 100%

Comment: I got it working by adding two page overlays then doing this `$('#nav li#dsm').on('click', function(){
        $('#page-overlay').toggleClass('active');
        $('#page-overlay2').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('#nav li#king').on('click', function(){
        $('#page-overlay2').toggleClass('active');
        $('#page-overlay').removeClass('active');
    });`